# Listar dados de duas tabelas não relacionadas em uma mesma view

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tenho uma view chamada formulário onde preciso que apareça, no campo select, os Estados(UF) vindos do MySQL. Tenho a `EstadoController` onde no método index faço a listagem usando o all. Agora, quero que essa listagem apareça na view formulário cujo a rota é: `Route::get('/formulario', 'FormularioController@create');`

A `EstadoController` está assim:

```
public function index(Estado $estado){       
    $retornoAllEstado = $estado->all();
    return view('painel-adm.formulario', compact('retornoAllEstado'));
}
```

Mas quando faço o foreach na view formulario, me deparo com erro:

```
<select class="custom-select" name="qpae_uf_rg">              
    @foreach($retornoAllEstado as $estado)
        <option value="1">{{$estado->uf}}</option>
    @endforeach          
</select>
```

Erro gerado: `Undefined variable: retornoAllEstado`...

**FormularioController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/* Usando a model Formulario */
use App\Models\Painel\Formulario;

class FormularioController extends Controller
{
    private $formulario;


    public function __construct(Formulario $formulario)
    {

        $this->formulario = $formulario;
    }

    public function index()
    {

    }


    public function create()
    {
        return view('painel-adm.formulario');
    }  

    public function store(Request $request)
    {       


    }

    public function show($id)
    {

    }

    public function edit($id)
    {

    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {

    }
}
```

**formulario.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-1">
        <label>UF</label>

        <select class="custom-select" name="uf">              
            @foreach($retornoAllEstado as $estado)
                <option value="1">{{$estado->uf}}</option>
            @endforeach          
        </select>           

    </div>
```

Comment: executa um `dd($retornoAllEstado);`após a linha que você pega todos os registros, e me fale o resultado.

Comment: Bom, retornou um array com os 27 itens, porém para eu ver o resultado sem erro, tive que criar uma rota Route::get('/estados-listar', 'EstadoController@index'); Mas agora precisa que essas listagem de UF apareça na minha view formulario.

Comment: Atualiza a pergunta e coloca o controller  que retorna desse formulário e a view. .

Comment: Não sei se fui muito claro. Quando eu digito no navegador /estados-listar abre a view estado.blade.php e aparece corretamente a listagem dos UF. Agora, preciso que essa listagem apareça na view formulario.blade.php

Comment: Faz um teste na resposta que dei e ve se é isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altere o método `create()`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Estado;
/**
* 
* code..
*/
public function create()
{
    $retornoAllEstado = new Estado::all();
    return view('painel-adm.formulario', compact('retornoAllEstado'));
} 
/**
* 
* code..
*/
```

> lembre de chamar o model no incio de sua classe use `App/Estado;`

Teste e veja se funciona como necessita.

Comment: Ok, deu certo! Porém, uma dúvida. Eu fiz essa alteração na FormularioController, porém a EstadoController não estou usando para nada. Eu consigo fazer o all na EstadoController e depois exibir a listagem na view formulario Route::get('/formulario', 'FormularioController@create'); ???

Comment: @Barraviera não entendi sua pergunta, mas essa `EstadoController` o máximo que você poderia usar seria para gestão, eu acho que você está confundindo o `controller` com o `model`. mas me explica melhor o que se quer pra eu tentar te ajudar.

Comment: Eu tenho a rota que mostra o formulario Route::get('/formulario', 'FormularioController@create'); Então, eu gostaria que quando eu digitasse /formulario a listagem de estados aparecesse no select do formulario. Isso já está funcionando, mas estou puxando essa listagem com o all na FormularioController e não na EstadoController. Estou iniciando no laravel, talvez eu esteja confundindo algo. Então, pelo que me parece é que eu não preciso ter uma controller específica para cada view?

Comment: @Barraviera da uma olhada nesses posts que fiz a alguns anos atrás [Laravel - Bulfaitelo](https://www.bulfaitelo.com.br/2017/04/tutorial-laravel-para-iniciantes-parte2.html), creio que você está confundindo o controller com o model, o Laravel "trabalha" com MVC, model (basicamente os dados) view (o retorno visual para o cliente) Controller (basicamente a parte lógica). o fato de você ter um controller EstadoController não quer dizer que ele tenha que ser usado, pois ele é só um controller.

Comment: Ótimo artigo! Vai me ajudar bastante.

Answer (score 1):

coloca um dd(&retornoAllEstado) provável que vc veja ela vazia, isso porque seu all() esta rodando na variável $estado. o que não é normal no index

sugestão:

```
$retornoAllEstado = Estado::all();
```

Comment: Funcionou também, porém tive que criar uma rota Route::get('/estados-listar', 'EstadoController@index'); Agora preciso que essa listagem apareça na view formulario Route::get('/formulario', 'FormularioController@create');